# How to transform Longitude/Latitude degree to UTM? R. rgdal, sp

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

My data is in latitude and longitude projection in the form of degrees, minutes and seconds. This has been and stored in text form (`character-class`, Ignore the `row.names`).

```
> pasaporte
         Latitud        Longitud
4  13°50¨52" sur 73°45¨12" oeste
36    13°01¨ sur    75°05¨ oeste
46 13°09¨26" sur 74°13¨22" oeste
```

By means of the [answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-August/249374.html) provided in the mailing list, I've transformed the data to decimal form...

```
> pasaporte
    Latitud Longitud
4  13.84778 73.75333
36 13.01667 75.08333
46 13.15722 74.22278
```

After that, I've transformed the `data.frame` to a `SpatialPoints` object.

```
xy <- data.frame(cbind(round(pasaporte[, 'Longitud'], 5), round(pasaporte[, 'Latitud'], 5))) #Rounded the decimals out of doubt of it interfering later
xy <- SpatialPoints(coords = xy,
                proj4string =  CRS('+proj=longlat +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'))
```

Then proceeded to transform the projection via `spTransform`

```
xy_utm <- spTransform(xy, CRS('+proj=utm +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84:0,0,0'))
```

I've converted the first coordinate in the example, using [this website](http://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html) (make shure to provide the negative since the coordinates refer to South and West), and provides the following coordinates: **633726.46 mE 8468757.51 mN Zone 18L**, which is correct. In contrast the `sp` object after the transformation is:

```
SpatialPoints:
           X1       X2
[1,] 12051333 14804033
[2,] 12569894 14792671
[3,] 12301330 14684870
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=utm +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0
```

The `spTransform` manual specifically mentions that the metadata should be correctly provided. My data uses the WGS84 ellipsoid and lies in the 18L zone. To be more precise the [epsg:32718](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32718/). Where am I'm going wrong?

Comment: This should be ask here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to "project" (i.e. multiply by -1) the points in the -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000 bounds, as they are lying in the southern and western hemispheres.

```
library(sp)

pasaporte <- structure(list(Latitud = c(13.84778, 13.01667, 13.15722), 
                            Longitud = c(73.75333, 75.08333, 74.22278)),
                       .Names = c("Latitud", "Longitud"), class = "data.frame", 
                       row.names = c("4", "36", "46"))

pasaporte <- pasaporte * -1

pasaporte
#      Latitud  Longitud
# 4  -13.84778 -73.75333
# 36 -13.01667 -75.08333
# 46 -13.15722 -74.22278

# Conversion into SpatialPoints
coordinates(pasaporte) <- ~Longitud+Latitud
# Setting default projection
proj4string(pasaporte) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')

pasaporte
# SpatialPoints:
#     Longitud   Latitud
# 4  -73.75333 -13.84778
# 36 -75.08333 -13.01667
# 46 -74.22278 -13.15722
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:4326
# +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

# Projection
# Be sure to have rgdal first installed.
xy_utm <- spTransform(pasaporte, CRS('+init=epsg:32718'))
xy_utm
# SpatialPoints:
#    Longitud Latitud
# 4  634726.5 8468758
# 36 490964.2 8561019
# 46 584231.8 8545348
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:32718 +proj=utm
# +zone=18 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
# +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: correct; this will only work, however, if package `rgdal` is installed.